# Where can I find the source code for android's Mac Filetransfer tool?

Tags: android

where can I find the source code for http://www.android.com/filetransfer/ please?

Comment: Did you manage to find the source? I've been aching for a way to turn of its autostart...

Comment: @Hugo Have you found it yet ?

Comment: @Ahmed I stopped looking unfortunately